# How to show table rows as form inputs without affecting style of table rows

Tags: php, css, laravel, forms, laravel-5.8

I have a table and retrieved some data with this table at the Blade.

Now I have added a checkbox as the first column of this table.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('finalFestival') }}">
   @csrf
   <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <th>Choose to pay</th>
         <th>Tracking Code</th>
         <th>Date of Submission</th>
         ...
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach( $my_plans as $plan )
      <tr>
         <td><input class="form-check-input" name="choose_to_pay" type="radio" value="checked"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="fsp_id" value="{{ $plan->fsp_id }}"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="plan_date" value="{{ jdate( strtotime( $plan->created_at ) )->format( 'Y/m/d' ) }}"></td>
         ....
      </tr>
   @endforeach
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the output of this goes here:

[screenshot of current table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fxek.png)

But I don't the white area if `<input>` appears around the value of it. I just want to display the input with `name` & their custom `value` just like the default behavior of `<table>` rows:

[screenshot of desired table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKbnh.png)

In the image above, I didn't specify any `<input>` for each `<td>`, as soon as I define them, it will show the inputs with White Space surrounding the value.

So how to remove this space and display the inputs just like default table `<td>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input{
    background-color : #e4e4e4;
    border : none;
    outline : none;
}
```